# Handle Zookeeper session timeout for Watchers

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-curator

I am using curator lib for all the Zookeeper operations. I have a client that is watching an ephemeral node (event = Node Deletion). If there is a session timeout (expiration) while watching the node it throws AsyncEventException. Now I want to monitor that Ephemeral node again so I can use the reset method on the AsyncEventException. But if during this time if the Ephemeral node gets deleted then I will not be able to capture that event? What is the best way of handling this situation neatly?

Comment: I suggest you use https://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/persistent-node.html instead. It's a Curator recipe that will keep an ephemeral node alive for you through network partitions, etc.

Comment: Thanks will look for it, I just had one more question when there is a Session expiration is the reset method also invoked that will close and create the new ZK Handle. I am asking coz I am assuming curator lib does that for us and we don;t have to close and create a new ZK handle then

Comment: Also PersistentNode might not work for us because the client that is watching the ephemeral node does not create that node. The ephemeral node is created by some other client

Comment: In that case, it would be easier to use a NodeCache to watch the node: https://curator.apache.org/curator-recipes/node-cache.html

Comment: Thanks that actually will solve my problem. If you can plz answer the other question I had then it will be very helpful.

Comment: "when there is a Session expiration is the reset method also invoked that will close and create the new ZK Handle" - We have a tech note on how Curator handles sessions: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CURATOR/TN14